# Convolution image filter implementation formula

Tags: matlab, image-processing, convolution

I need to apply mean removal filter to an image with convolution.

The kernel is:

```
-1 -1 -1           k11 k12 k13 
-1  9 -1   (coord) k21 k22 k23
-1 -1 -1           k31 k32 k33
```

`Factor = 1, Offset = 0`

If my matrix coordinates are

```
m11 m12 m13
m21 m22 m23
m31 m32 m33
```

**1.** In order to calculate the resulting pixel (from the center of matrix), shouldn't the formula look like this?

```
pixel = m11 * k11 + m12 * k12 + m13 * k13
      + m21 * k21 + m22 * k22 + m23 * k23
      + m31 * k31 + n32 * k32 + m33 * k33

pixel /= factor
pixel += offset
```

The image looks ok, but there are slight changes if I compare my filtered image to one filtered by other program by using `diff`.

**2.** The new pixel value should be put back to the input matrix, so that it is used in the calculation of the next pixels?

**3.** Also, bonus question: If the number of pixels is the same, how is it possible that the filtered image has a different size?

Comment: Not a C question as nothing applies to C - tag removed.

Comment: **1**. Looks right but you didn't post how the filtering is being computed in both cases so its difficult to say why there are differences. Possibly rounding differences or boundary effects. **2**. Convolution doesn't happen in place, you always reference the original image when referencing to m11,m12, etc... **3**. The size can change depending on what you expect at the image boundaries, to explicitly define the padding and output size options see [the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfilter.html#inputarg_options).

Comment: @jodag **2.**  Still not clear to me. Before I calculate pixel 2, should I update the pixel 1 in the input matrix, so it influences the calculation of second one? **3.** My bad. I forgot that a 3 digit number on a text file takes is 3 characters, not 1.

Comment: "Before I calculate pixel 2, should I update the pixel 1 in the input matrix so it influences the calculation of the second one?" The answer is **No**. You need to have a source image where you retrieve the values m11,m12,etc.. and destination image where you store the resulting values. The source doesn't change during the computation.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought. But I can't find the problem. I generate the image for comparison from GIMP. I am using text grayscale pgm images (P2). Maybe there's something wrong in the above formula.

Comment: If you fixed your code as suggested by @jodag (not overwriting your input but creating a new output image), and your results are still different, then we need to know exactly: (1) what you did in GIMP to get the image you're comparing with, (2) the code where you compute the filtered image, and (3) the code where you compare the two images.

Comment: The `factor` and `offset` values are not needed in a convolution. Also, your equation is strictly wrong, though in this case it doesn't matter because your kernel is symmetric. You would multiply `m11*k33`, `m12*k32`, etc. That is, mirror the kernel.

Comment: @Cris Luengo Good catch, I'm so used to looking at symmetric kernels I didn't notice that. What OP has described is actually correlation not convolution.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I think this is the answer I am looking for. Can you please post the full formula as an answer? Ignore the symmetry of the filter used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Definition) is defined as

## Question 1

[image: convolution equation]

*f* is your image, and *g* is your kernel (or the other way around, really doesn't matter). The 2D case is similar, with *t* and *τ* being 2-vectors, and using a double integral. Note the different sign of *τ* in the evaluation of *f* and *g*. This implies that one of the two is being mirrored with respect to the other.

So your equation is strictly wrong. You are using a symmetric kernel, so there's no difference in mirroring, but the equation should read

```
pixel = m11 * k33 + m12 * k32 + m13 * k31
      + m21 * k23 + m22 * k22 + m23 * k21
      + m31 * k13 + n32 * k12 + m33 * k11
```

The `offset` value plays no role in the convolution, and the `factor` can be mixed in with the kernel values `kxx`:

```
pixel = ( m11*k33 + m12*k32 + m13*k31 ) * factor
```

is the same as

```
pixel = m11*k33*factor + m12*k32*factor + m13*k31*factor
```

So you can just pre-multiply all `kxx` with factor before you compute the convolution.

## Question 2

No, the new pixel value should be written to a new image. If you write it back to the input image, you'll be using that value when computing the result for the next pixel, so you'll get a wrong result.

## Question 3

The result of the convolution operation for a pixel at the edge of the image reads "out of bounds". It needs to read the value of the pixel outside the image. You can choose to read 0 there, or to fill the values in some other way. Some software instead chooses to not compute those pixels instead, yielding a smaller output image. Some software actually computes more pixels, if you extend the image with zeros, the result of the convolution at a pixel just outside the image will read some of the image's pixels at the edge.

[MATLAB's `conv2` function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv2.html) takes an optional argument that is one of `'full'`, `'same'` or `'valid'`. `'full'`, which is the default, does this last thing, where it computes the convolution at all locations where the image pixels have some influence. The output will be `size(f)+size(g)-1`. `'valid'` produces a smaller image, where it doesn't need to read outside the image domain. `'same'` produces an image of the same size as the input image.